# dust.js template data update

Tags: javascript, templates, dust.js

is there a way to update the template data without re-rendering the dust template.

What i mean is this.

I have a successful dust template that outputs the following:

```
<ul>
    <li>John</li>
    <li>Mark</li>
    <li>Jim</li>
    <li>Nick</li>
</ul>
```

when i do an update on my data, for example: change "John" to "Peter" and sent the result to the database, do I need to re-render the dust template again (which will take all data and re-draw it on the client) or is there any way to tell dust to update ONLY the li with the value "John" ( and change it to "peter")?

Comment: Dust does not support data binding in this way. You cannot render only part of a template.

Comment: that's sad.  I'll look if there is a plugin that can work along dust.  I'll post it if i find anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use smaller template components.  Here's what I mean:

list.tl:

```
<ul>
  <li>{>"listItem" name="John"/}</li>
  <li>{>"listItem" name="Mark"/}</li>
  <li>{>"listItem" name="Jim"/}</li>
  <li>{>"listItem" name="Nick"/}</li>
</ul>
```

listItem.tl:

```
{name}
```

Then when you, let's say, click on an element, you could do something like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('li').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var element = this;
  dust.render('listItem', {name: 'MyNewName'}, function(error, output) {
    element.innerHTML = output;
  });
}
```

With this, you only re-render the part that is actually being changed.

EDIT 1: You don't need the .tl extension when calling another template, so got rid of that.

Comment: excellent suggestion.  I think it will work.  thank you for your input

Comment: Glad it could help.  Also, I missed the part where you said you were updating it in the database so I would put the dust.render inside the success callback of the Ajax function.  That way if the update database call fails, your page won't display incorrect information.